# Hubot installation error where --create does not create a directory

Tags: node.js, npm, hubot

I'm trying to heroku-deploy a hubot application (into Slack, if that matters).  I'm developing locally on Ubuntu 14.04.  I am closely [following these instructions](https://github.com/tinyspeck/hubot-slack).

Here are my steps...

```
sudo apt-get install node npm
sudo npm install -g hubot coffee-script
hubot --create myrobot
```

However, nothing at all is created, there is no myrobot directory---and there is no statement of error.  Honestly, I'm not even sure where to look for debugging information.

It doesn't make a difference, but is good practice to be doing all this within a cloned git:hubot-slack directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by creating a symlink from nodejs to node.